# table design not in a single line

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I used [material-ui table](https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/) now as you can see there is a header that has a break space in multiline from it I want it to a single line is there any way to do it in a single line?
for more, I am sharing [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-i4f8x?file=/demo.js) you can edit the code and tell me how it can be possible using material UI or any other CSS.
There is no issue if there is scroll
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the first column to be wide enough to have its heading all on one line?

Comment: yes i want all column in a single line in a wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the property `white-space: 'nowrap'` to both the table cell and header. Something like this:

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
  head: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: 16,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  }
}))(TableCell);
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-377jx?file=/demo.js